# Error #1136 But columns seem to match values when uploading a backed up wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've been trying to upload a backed up wp database to my server but I keep getting this error in the **posts table**

```
#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 37
```

This is the code that gets dumped into the database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `eel_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text NOT NULL,
  `post_excerpt` text NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
  `comment_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `ping_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `post_password` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to_ping` text NOT NULL,
  `pinged` text NOT NULL,
  `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content_filtered` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `guid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
  `post_mime_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `post_name` (`post_name`),
  KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  KEY `post_author` (`post_author`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=247 ;




INSERT INTO `eel_posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES
(121, 1, '2015-01-12 20:45:09', '2015-01-12 23:45:09', 'Se sugiere que exista una entidad en el gobierno, preferentemente en el Ministerio de Energía, que pueda hacer seguimiento y auditoría de las EEL, además de aconsejar a los diversos territorios de cómo poder alcanzar las metas y postular a los diversos fondos existentes. Para no tener mucha burocracia, se pueden revisar las metas en los Municipios cada 4 y/o 5 años. Es importante enfocarse en pocos indicadores pero que sean importantes.', 'Seguimiento', '', 'inherit', 'closed', 'open', '', '109-revision-v1', '', '', '2015-01-12 20:45:09', '2015-01-12 23:45:09', '', 109, 'http://eel.cl/eel/sin-categoria/109-revision-v1/', 0, 'revision', '', 0),
```

Answer (score 0):

That means you have 23 columns  but you have missed the values of some columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try delete last comma (outer comma).

Try this statement:

```
INSERT INTO `eel_posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES
(121, 1, '2015-01-12 20:45:09', '2015-01-12 23:45:09', 'Se sugiere que exista una entidad en el gobierno, preferentemente en el Ministerio de Energía, que pueda hacer seguimiento y auditoría de las EEL, además de aconsejar a los diversos territorios de cómo poder alcanzar las metas y postular a los diversos fondos existentes. Para no tener mucha burocracia, se pueden revisar las metas en los Municipios cada 4 y/o 5 años. Es importante enfocarse en pocos indicadores pero que sean importantes.', 'Seguimiento', '', 'inherit', 'closed', 'open', '', '109-revision-v1', '', '', '2015-01-12 20:45:09', '2015-01-12 23:45:09', '', 109, 'http://eel.cl/eel/sin-categoria/109-revision-v1/', 0, 'revision', '', 0)
```

Comment: The code inserts multiple values in the the table, this is just one of them, that's why the last comma is there